# Open and Edit *.DOCX File in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I copy a DOCX file from an app internal folder (files) to the media store (DOCUMENTS) and return a URI. Using Intent I open the file in Microsoft Office Word on my Android tablet. I can also edit the file. Unfortunately, after saving the file, the URI for the MediaStore is no longer valid or no longer exists. If I do the same with Google DOCS, the URI is still there. But when I open the Files app on my tablet, the file is there. Does anyone know any advice?

```
public Uri copyToMediaStore(Context context, String url, String fileName, String customPath) {
     
        Uri contentUri = null;

        File file = new File(fileName);
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/" + customPath);

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        contentUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues);

        try {
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream output = resolver.openOutputStream(contentUri);

            if (output != null) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                output.close();
            }

            input.close();
            return contentUri;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
    public void startActivity(PluginCall call) {
        String uri = call.getString("contentUri");
        try {
            Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setData(fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(call, intent, "getActivityResult");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("startFileActivity exeption", String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
```